# How do I move Thunderbird tags from one computer to another

Tags: tags, thunderbird

I recently got a new laptop. I installed Thunderbird on it (102.2), Updated Thunderbird on the old computer to the same version, Closed Thunderbird, copy the contents of the default release profile to the new computer, Closed Thunderbird, cleared the contents of the profile, and pasted the content of the old profile from the old computer. almost everything works. All of my tags are there. I can tag new messages. all of my old messages are there in my inbox, but none of them are tagged. how can I get the messages tagged properly? it is an IMAP account.